# How to Sanitise CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a raw csv from which I am creating a dataframe to do so some data cleaning and then convert it back to csv. But the final output I am getting is not in a proper format. so I wanted to know the way on how I can sanitize the csv.

For example I have the raw csv in the form:

```
id,text,value
1,'hello',4
3,,2
```

I wanted the csv to be in the normal form

```
  +----+----------+-------+
  | id |   text   | value |
  +----+----------+-------+
  |  1 |    hello |     4 |
  |  3 |    0     |     2 |
  +----+----------+-------+
```

Santizing can be done before or after processing inside the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by proper format as your first csv is already in csv form. But to fill your `na` results, you can do this:

```
df.fillna('0')
```